# OData JSON camelCase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I want to use the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver for the OData JSON response. How can I achieve this. With the follwoing Code Fragment only the webapi calls are considered.

regards

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // New code:
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Configuration>("Configurations");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();


        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = settings;

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only want to serialize the payload in the response as camel case and the one in request is still pascal case?

Comment: Should be work in both directions (request model match should also be work)

Answer (score 29):

You can use the `EnableLowerCamelCase` extension method:

```
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;

var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
```

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn746676%28v=vs.118%29.aspx.

Comment: what about OData V3 ?

Comment: @DotNetWise: I think - without having checked, admittedly - that Marko's original question actually shows how to obtain this with OData V3.

Comment: The above EnableLowerCamelCase works only for properties. It does not work for entity types and entity sets. Any suggestions for that ?

Comment: @Venki - you are probably better off asking that as a new question within which you clarify your actual needs :)

Answer (score 0):

This sample may meet your requirement, just start from this file:

The samples have since moved [here](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataModelAliasingSample).